# Multi Language web applicaion in asp.net on dropdown change

Tags: asp.net, multilingual

I want to create multi language web application simple asp.net (no MVC). Dropdown has English, French and Dutch language.

I don't want to create any language resource file, get corresponding data in different language from database or any hard-coded variables holding different data for different language.

Reason behind that is asp page contains lots of data, label text, etc. and it will take so much of time to create resource file for each language

I searched many solution but the links I read has implemented in one of the above ways.

Can't I create a asp page in default English language and as dropdown changes, just encode it in selected language in dropdown?

Can that be possible? If so, can anybody provide some code or link?